# return get_the_tag_list with whitespace removed

Tags: filters, tags

I need to `get_the_tag_list` but want to remove whitespace **within** individual tags.

Thus, 
    `firefox, internet explorer, opera`
becomes
    `firefox, internetexplorer, opera`

All the filters I found removed whitespace from the HTML, not the content itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tags = get_the_tags();
$tag_links = array();

foreach((array)$tags as $tag)
  $tag_links[] = '<a href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'" rel="tag">'.str_replace(' ', '', $tag->name)).'</a>';

echo implode(', ', $tag_links);
```

Comment: Wordpress gives me an error because of the extra `)` after `$tag->name` but once I corrected that, it worked fine. Thanks!